# enviar datos de ESP8266 a Thingspeak

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Hace unos dos años empece a gestar un proyecto de energía solar desde cero: cargador, inversor, sistema de control, etc. y pronto descubrí que Arduino era ideal para controlar todo el asunto. Poco tiempo después le incorpore internet y entre al mundo de IoT, habia conseguido enviar información muy confiablemente con los comandos AT, pero a este momento arduino quedo chico y, para no tener que mudar todo el proyecto hacia un Mega o algo parecido, decidí encargarle al ESP8266 la parte de transmisión de datos a la red, así aprendí a programarlo al ESP y conseguí que se comunique con Arduino enviando y recibiendo datos desde una app que armé en android.

El problema surgio cuando quise enviar la información minuto a minuto a Thingspeak que antes enviaba muy bien mediante comandos AT. Envía un valor o dos y ya no envía mas.

Este es el código del ESP8266, la primera parte recibe el código de la app a través del servidor y la envía a traves del puerto serie a arduino, en el medio comprueba solicitudes de cambio de usuario y contraseña del router al que se conecta la estación. Todo esto funciona perfecto.
Después esta la parte que conecta a arduino con, ya sea la red local o internet, para eso el codigo proviniente desde arduino tiene un identificador "L$" si tiene que ser transmitida a LAN o "I$" si va a internet, la parte que transmite a LAN funciona OK, la parte que transmite a THingspeak es la que falla.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
WiFiClient TCP;
WiFiClient Thingspeak;
WiFiServer Solar1(6556);

String SSIDR = "WIFIJAA";                                  //router SSID
String PASS = "JOSESO01";                                  //router CONTRASEÑA
String IP = "184.106.153.149" ;
int PORT = 80 ;
int c;
void setup() {

  //WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);                                   //cambiando a modoo STA+AP 
  WiFi.softAP("******", "*******",4);
  WiFi.begin(SSIDR, PASS);
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Solar1.begin();
  WiFi.setAutoReconnect(true);
}

void loop() {

  WiFiClient TCP = Solar1.available();
  if (!TCP) {
    return;
  }
  TCP.setTimeout(500);

  //------------De android a arduino----------------------
  String E = TCP.readStringUntil('\r');                       //Entrada de datos desde TCP
  Serial.println (E);                                         //Transferencia de esos datos a arduino
 
  //------------Configuracion de estacion (local)---------
  //-------------------SSID-------------------------------

  c = E.indexOf("%SSID=");                                    //Deteccion de SSID req
  if (c != -1) {
    E.remove(0, 6);
    if (E != "-1") {
      SSIDR = E  ;
      String mensaje = "SSID:" + SSIDR ;
      TCP.print(mensaje + "\r");
      WiFi.disconnect();
      WiFi.begin(SSIDR, PASS);
      delay(5000);

    }
    String mensaje = "SSID:" + SSIDR ;
    TCP.print(mensaje + "\r");
    delay(100);
  }

  //-------------------CONTRASEÑA-------------------------

  c = E.indexOf("%CONTRA=");                                   //Deteccion de CONTRASEÑA req
  if (c != -1) {
    E.remove(0, 8);
    if (E != "-1") {
      PASS = E  ;
      String mensaje = "CONTRA:" + PASS ;
      TCP.print(mensaje + "\r");
      WiFi.disconnect();
      WiFi.begin(SSIDR, PASS);
      delay(5000);

    }
    String mensaje = "CONTRA:" + PASS ;
    TCP.print(mensaje + "\r");
    delay(100);
  }

  delay(500);

  //--------------------De Arduino a Android/web------------

  while (Serial.available()) {                                //Lectura de respuesta de arduino
    String R = Serial.readStringUntil('$');

    if ( R == "I") {                                          //Si va a "I"nternet transmite por Thingspeak
      R = Serial.readStringUntil('\r');
      Thingspeak.connect(IP, PORT);
      delay(200);
      Thingspeak.print(R + "\r\n");
      delay(200);
      Thingspeak.stop();
    }
    else if (R == "L") {                                      //Si va por "L"an transmite por TCP
      R = Serial.readStringUntil('\r');
      TCP.print(R + "\r");
      delay(100);
    }
  }
}
```

Este es el código de arduino que envia el String que debe enviarse a Thingspeak. GET1 contiene los datos de canal de Thingspeak de destino

```
void updateSensors() {
  String  cmd = "I$";
  cmd += GET1;
  cmd += "&field1=";
  cmd += conCaf(enerd, 0);
  cmd += "&field2=";
  cmd += conCaf(enerdac, 0);
  cmd += "&field3=";
  cmd += conCaf(enerdcp, 0);
  cmd += "&field4=";
  cmd += conCaf(enerdcb, 0);
  cmd += "&field5=";
  cmd += conCaf(potmax, 0);
  cmd += "&field6=";
  cmd += conCaf(dia, 0);
  wifi1.println(cmd);

}
```

conCaf es una función que convierte float a cadenas con el numero de decimales en el segundo parámetro.

Este es el código que funcionaba perfectamente antes enviando la información a Thingspeak:

```
void updateSensors() {
    wifi1.flush();
    String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=1,\"TCP\",\"";
    cmd += IP;
    cmd += "\",80";
    wifi1.println(cmd);
    delay(600);
    wifi1.flush();

    cmd = GET1;
    cmd += "&field1=";
    cmd += conCaf(enerd, 0);
    cmd += "&field2=";
    cmd += conCaf(enerdac, 0);
    cmd += "&field3=";
    cmd += conCaf(enerdcp, 0);
    cmd += "&field4=";
    cmd += conCaf(enerdcb, 0);
    cmd += "&field5=";
    cmd += conCaf(potmax, 0);
    cmd += "&field6=";
    cmd += conCaf(dia, 0);
    cmd += "\r\n";
    int strsize = cmd.length();
    wifi1.println("AT+CIPSEND=1," + String(strsize));
    delay(600);
    wifi1.print(cmd);
    delay(800);

    if (wifi1.find("SEND OK")) {      
      wifi1.println("AT+CIPCLOSE=1");
      delay(200);
    }
   }
  }

´´´
Les agradeceré enormemente cualquier aporte
```

Comment: ¿Para qué tienes un Arduino y un ESP8266? Con un ESP8266 basta y sobra. La única diferencia es el número de pines, que puedes solucionar con un multiplexor. Más aún, el ESP8266 puedes programarlo con Python, lo que te simplificaria mucho la vida.

Comment: Porque uso las 11 e/s digitales y las 5 analogicas para controlar la  estacion completa, el ESP solo toene 4 e/s digitales y no tiene entradas analogicas.